# Error "java.exe" exited with code 1 - Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard

I want to reduce size of .apk file, so I am checking *Enable ProGuard* option in Android project's property window but getting compile time errors

> Error "java.exe" exited with code 1.

I tried few things like

- Head size is already 1G.
- Android target version is 9.0(Pie).
- My Solutions Configuration in Release mode.

Log:

```
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax$a: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.Instrumentation: can't find referenced class com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.BuildInfo
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.Instrumentation: can't find referenced class com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.BuildInfo
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.InstrumentationCallbacks: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.RequestLine
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.RequestLine
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax$a: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax$a: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax$a: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax$a: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax$a: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
8>PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private.ax$a: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
8>PROGUARD : warning : there were 123 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
8>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2550,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 7 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am using proguard 4.7 file. I can't use latest proguard file as I am not allowed to download any external files. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please add the log here and not as some off-site resource

Comment: @Cheesebaron - I tried that but log (From VS output window) is _too long_ which going to look weird here. Moreover, SO editor not accepting that. Thank you.

Comment: Narrow it down to where it fails

Comment: @Cheesebaron - I have added log in question as short as needed for SO editor. Thank you.

Comment: org.apache.http is legacy in Google Play services. Which version of Play Services are you referencing? If it is the newest, you might be hitting a bug in the Xamarin bindings.

Comment: @Cheesebaron - Yes I am using latest version only. `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.60.1142.1
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.60.1142.1
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.60.1142.1`. Now what should I do?

Comment: Do you add `-dontwarn com.google.android. GMS`

`- dontwarn com. Google. Firebase. * *` in your proguard file

Comment: @LeoZhu - In proguard.cfg file do not have anything which starts from `dontwarn`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows#customizing-proguard, you should add them to your customizing-proguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I have found solutions for this issue.

First download latest Proguard file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/) unzip and copy to sdk path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`, this path could be different in your case.

There must be already one proguard folder, rename that to proguard.old. Now from proguard.old folder copy and paste `proguard-android`, `proguard-android-optimize`, `proguard-project` files to newly created proguard folder.

After that need to follow below steps

- Create txt file somewhere in your PC and change extension to `.cfg`.
- Change proguard.cfg file Encoding using Notepad++ to UTF-8 without BOM and Save As somewhere.
- Now add this new proguard.cfg to your android project level.
- Change proguard.cfg file build action to ProguardConfiguration
- Clean your project.

If you are getting `warnings` with prefix progurd like this

> PROGUARD : warning : com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.private

Now you need to add this package to your custom proguard.cfg file like

```
-dontwarn com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.**
```

With `-dontwarn` do not use keyword `class`. Here `**` takes all child classes of given package.

If you are getting `exception` then you need to find out which library causing issue and add that in proguard.cfg file with `-keep` keyword

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

If you see your full log carefully progaurd gives all warnings to make us easy to find out issue.